# Export animated flash objects to Marmalade SDK

Tags: flash, animation, vector-graphics, marmalade, flash-cs6

How do I export (use) my animated vector objects (made with Flash Professional) at Marmalade SDK? I don't want to program animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Marmalade, but on their front page I see it supports app development under HTML5,CSS3,JS.

In this case, it should be possible to use [Adobe's CreateJS toolkit for Flash CS6](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html) 
Getting started resources:

1. [CreateJS devnet article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/createjs/articles/getting-started.html)
2. [Getting Started with the Flash Professional Toolkit for CreateJS](http://tv.adobe.com/show/getting-started-with-flash-professional-toolkit-for-createjs/) videos